# Защита GET параметров

Tags: защита, php

Помогите новичку.
Подскажите как правильно проверять и защищать GET-параметры?
Припустим они отправляются по нажатию на ссылку:

```
<a href="?name=good>Click</a>
```

Как проверить теперь переменную получаемую $_GET['name']?Пользователь ведь может подставить свои значения?
А post данные также нужно проверять?
Читал про htmlspecialchar() ее можно использовать для полной защиты?

UPDATE:
Пользуетесь вы какие-нибудь функции для проверка SQL и другого рода атак?Читал недавно что нужно проверять и запрещать такие слова как WHERE,UNION,sql и.т.д. Может поделетись рабочими кодами?

Comment: Люди люди! Что вы делаете! Нельзя передавать явно ГЕТ в ссылках! Нет нет и нет. Используйте ЧПУ!

Comment: @stk можно, если проверять все принимаемые параметры на допустимость.  
Да и ЧПУ не делает код безопасным. Безопасным его опять же делает проверка всего что приходит от пользователя.

Comment: @ReinRaus, пускай они даже будут верными и допустимые но ссылки вида 
`<a href='mysite.ru?p=somepage&a=1&b=2&ip_h=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70&session_encode=cXdlcnR5dWlvcFtdYXNkZmdoamtsOyd6eGN2Ym5tLC5xd2VydHl1aW9wW11hc2RmZ2hqa2w7J3p4Y3Zibm0sLnF3ZXJ0eXVpb3BbXWFzZGZnaGprbDsnenhjdmJubSwucXdlcnR5dWlvcFtdYXNkZmdoamtsOyd6eGN2Ym5tLC5xd2VydHl1aW9wW11hc2RmZ2hqa2w7J3p4Y3Zibm0sLnF3ZXJ0eXVpb3BbXW4='>ссылка</a>` не годятся. Всю дрянь в post или ещё куда. Это плохая привычка - ухудшает восприятие и юзабельность

Comment: Пользователям все равно используете Вы ЧПУ или нет, ничего не ухудшиться.  
Это хорошо для SEO, когда адрес отражает суть страницы, а пользователю и человеку который ищет уязвимости все равно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за коментарии

Comment: Для интереса создал опрос :)  
[Как Вы относитесь к ЧПУ](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/81011033/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Внимание:** данный ответ не имеет никакого отношения к "защите", а представляет собой коллекцию суеверий, которые были распространены среди пользователей РНР много лет назад. См. подробный разбор этих суеверий в ответе ниже.

> При этом само по себе понятие обобщенной "защиты GET-параметров" не имеет смысла. Невозможно защититься от всего сразу. Так можно только испортить входящие данные. Защита всегда должна быть только **конкретной**, в зависимости от контекста. К примеру, защищать SQL запросы от инъекций надо с помощью подготовленных выражений (причем защищать надо любые данные, а не только "GET-параметры"); При **выводе** данных в HTML, необходимо применять функцию `htmlspecialchars()` (опять же, любых данных, безотносительно источника их происхождения); при выводе в Javascript использовать `json_encode()`; И так далее.

> Также важно не путать защиту с *валидацией* входящих данных. Валидация действительно делается на входе, но, во-первых, она не имеет отношения к защите, а только повышает удобство и предсказуемость кода, а во-вторых, все равно не должна быть одинаковой для всех параметров, а применяться к каждому отдельно.

через get параметры можно можно и базу своровать, имея лишь прямые руки. Так что постоянно нужно проверять вводимые значения.
Я зачастую использую эти три функции при очистке параметров GET и POST:

```
$str = $_GET['параметр'];
$str = trim($str);
$str = stripslashes($str);
$str = htmlspecialchars($str);
```

После получаю безопасную строку, которую уже сравниваю. Если она должна быть только числовой, то проверяю на is_numeric() и так далее.

В вашем случае можно использовать то что я написал выше, а еще проверить строку на максимальную длину. Наверное у Вас name может быть не более 15 символов(к примеру). Так что проверяйте и на это. Потом проверяйте на иные символы с помощью preg_match.
То же самое и с POST запросами.

У меня в проекте даже функция отдельная есть:

```
function formatstr($str) 
    {
        $str = trim($str);
        $str = stripslashes($str);
        $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
        return $str;
    }
```

удобно ;)

Comment: Спасибо !!
а что касается Post можно?

Comment: Да конечно. То же самое. Всегда надо проверять. Только для post используйте еще и максимальную длину в полях ввода. Чтобы лишнее не ввели. 
p.s. Если вдруг не знаете, как пост запрос принять, то вот: $_POST['name']. Вдруг. Но я уверен - Вы знаете всё!

Comment: А почему вы не используете встроенную в php [фильтрацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filter.php)?

    $str = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'str', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Answer (score 5):

М-да. Я немного развею миф на счёт трёх волшебных функций для начала.

- `trim()` - Удаляет слева и справа пробельные символы. Используется для удобства, но к безопасности отношения не имеет.
- `stripslashes()` - на 100% бессмысленная функция, была нужна 20 лет назад, когда РНР сам портил входящие данные, добавляя слеши к кавычкам.
- `htmlspecialchars()` - название говорит за себя, эта функция экранирует управляющие символы HTML. То есть она должна применяться не для входящих данных, а при выводе любых данных в HTML.

Если же говорить про защиту от SQL инъекций, на хабре есть хорошая статья на эту тему:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/148701/

Comment: вопрос 2 года назад задан.... щас от sql инъекций защищаются с помошью bind param, а когда это не прокатывают забивают  баг вендору базы....

Comment: А вот за это спасибо. я тоже новичок, и только изучаю все эти прелести. Поищем инфу уже в нете :З



Тью, ясненько, я им пользуюсь, но думал он только совершает подмену.

Answer (score 0):

есть еще один вариант, если параметр должен быть только числом: функция intval()
Тогда не нужно париться насчет проверки $_GET